# How to do responsive SVG and text side by side?

Tags: jquery, svg, resize

I'm trying to create a header that consists of a square SVG logo and a name, side by side, that will resize nicely with the browser window.

I've got two DIVs in my header, #logo and #name. I'm using jQuery FitText on #name, and wrote a simple script for #logo to get the height from #name and use that for its height and width. Relevant bits are here: http://jsfiddle.net/dBcdz/

```
<header>
    <div id="name">MY NAME</div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</header>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var setLogo = new function () {
        var $size = $('#name').height();
        $('#logo').css({
            'height': $size,
            'width': $size
        });
    }
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    setLogo();
});
```

The problem is, I can't get both of these divs to resize with the window. At best only the name resizes, or I have to reload the page for it to look right. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, I'm caching the selectors so it's more efficient:

```
var $name = $("#name"),
    $logo = $('#logo');

function resize() { 
   var $size = $name.fitText().height();
   $logo.css({
     'height': $size,
     'width': $size
   });
}

$(document).ready(resize);
$(window).resize(resize);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aXWZC/

Answer (score 0):

This fix your code:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dBcdz/2/)

```
function setLogo() {
    var $size = $('#name').height();
    $('#logo').css({
        'height': $size,
            'width': $size
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $("#name").fitText();
        setLogo();
    }).resize();
});
```